# recursive function get "Variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier) error"

Tags: objective-c, recursion, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

I want to send `AFNetworking` requests consequently in a queue. I create a recursive function as below for this aim:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

     NSLog(@"Start ...");

    [self sentTest:0];
}

- (void) sentTest:(int)i{

    if(i >= 10)
    {
        NSLog(@"Finished");
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"sending message %d ...", i);

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [@{@"param1":     @"value1",
                                     @"param2":     @"value2",
                                     } mutableCopy];
    NSString *webServiceUrl = @"MY_REST_SERVICE_URL";

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];


    [manager POST:webServiceUrl parameters:params success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"message sent successful %d", i);

        // Now call the method again
        [self sentTest:i++];

         return;
         } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"message sent failure %d", i);
             return;
    }];

}
```

I get this error:

```
Variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier)  error"
```

I know that I need to define block type, but I don't know how to use it in this recursive function.

Comment: OK lets start with `manager`.  That will be destroyed when the method ends, yes?  So how will it manage to do anything at all?

Comment: @trojanfoe There is no problem in destroyed manager, I just want to call this method again, so I could start new request just after the previous request finished. Yes, it is not the best solution, but it could solve the problem. I try other solutions too, but they are not working at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297033/queue-of-afnetworking-requests-with-dispatch-group-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some concerns that `manager` was being destroyed when the method ends, however it's being retained by the block.

I am not certain your code will work, however the actual error message relates to updating `i` in the block (and it would need to have the `__block` attribute applied), however there is no reason to increment `i` at all, simply pass in `i + 1` to the recursed method:

```
[self sentTest:i + 1];
```

(you had a missing semicolon in your code, so I am not convinced that is the real code or not).

Comment: it is a real code, I use your previous comment to solve it, using `__block int count = i` before the block, and `[self sentTest:++count]` inside the block, thank you anyway @trojanfoe

Comment: @SoheilNovinfard: No. It makes no sense for you to change `i` because nobody can possibly read that `i` again.